Noetherian functions and related notations.
Let $A, B$ be sets, $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a function from $A$ to $B$, where $A \subset B$.
The function $f$ can be considered as a binary relation on the set $B$.
If this relation is Noetherian (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian)
then $f$ can be naturally called a Noetherian function.
In other words, a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ is Noetherian iff:
a) $A \subset B$;
b) for any $x \in B$ there exists a finite sequence $s = (s_0, s_1, ..., s_k), k \geq 0$,  such that:

$s_0 = x$;

$s_k \in B\setminus A$;

if $s_{i-1} \in A$ then $s_i = f(s_{i-1})$  for  $i = 1, ..., k$;


Obviously, $s = (x, f(x), ..., f^k(x) )$.
Note, that $f$ for $x = s_k$ is not defined and we cannot continue the sequence $s$.
The sequence $s$ is unique for any $x \in B$.
So for any Noetherian function $f:A \rightarrow B$  a function $whseq:B \rightarrow seq(B)$ exists where $seq(B)$ denotes the set of all finite sequences over $B$
and for any $x \in B  \ \   whseq(f)(x)$ is the sequence $s$ defined above.
Also, for any Noetherian function $f:A \rightarrow B$ a function $wh(f) = F[x:B, Last(whseq(f)(x))]$ can , using a version of lambda notation,
be introduced (here $Last(s)$ denotes the last element of an nonempty sequence $s$).
Have some notations(similar to $whseq$ and $wh$), associated with  Noetherian functions, ever been used in mathematics?
